# Is there really a Flex++ Scanner?

Tags: c++, bison, yacc, lex, flex++

I'm running on a Debian Squeeze and I get flex/flex++ installed using apt-get install flex.

However I noted that flex++ is just a sym link to flex. So, really exists an "program" flex++ that generate c++ scanners or is just a flex flag that I shoud switch?

Also, the common problem: Many examples on the internet can't "compile" under flex or flex++. Flex give the following error:

```
test.lex:1: invalid character: %
...
```

when processing an input with just:

```
%name Test
```

what is wrong here?

Flex/Flex++ version is 2.5.35

Comment: As a first guess, I would check to see if test.lex is saved as a UTF-8 file with a BOM. That trips up lots of these tools.

Comment: There is a good example in this page: http://www.thebinaryidiot.com/archives/2010/03/06/flex-bison-cpp-example/ I compiled and ran fine in my Debian Squeeze. I've installed bison with apt-get install bison

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is actually a Flex++ project, but it is separate to the original Flex:

- http://flexcpp.sourceforge.net/

Flex does support generating scanner code for use with C++, but it is classed as experimental (though it has been there for quite some time):

- [Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Cxx.html)

The symlink is explained by the fact that some programs modify their behaviour based on how they are invoked. For compatibility reasons, they check `argv[0]` and look at the executable name.  For example, when run as `flex++`, it can enable the `-+` flag for C++ support.

(BusyBox uses this technique to have one binary behave as many separate programs, saving space.)

Comment: According to the package specs at http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/flex the Flex in squeeze is definitely the usual http://flex.sf.net/ . Try using %option yyclass="Test" rather than %name.